# need to make a booking webpage that writes to another file

Tags: javascript, html

no matter what i try it wont write to the file

**HTML**

```html
<label> Firstname </label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" size="15"/> <br> <br>
<label> Lastname: </label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" size="15"/> <br> <br>
<label> number of people: </label>
<input type="number" id="number" size="15"/> <br> <br>
<label>what day would you like:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="day" size="15"/> <br> <br>
<button onclick="WriteToFile; document.getElementById('firstname').value = '';
  document.getElementById('firstname').value = ''; document.getElementById('lastname').value = '';
  document.getElementById('lastname').value = '';
  document.getElementById('number').value = '';
  document.getElementById('day').value = ''">book on in</button>
<br>
```

**Script**

```js
const booking = {
    firstName:getElementById("firstname"),
    lastName:getElementById("lastname"),
    people:getElementById("number")
};

import java.io.FileWriter;   // Import the FileWriter class
import java.io.IOException;  // Import the IOException class to handle errors

function WriteToFile {
    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("book.txt");
        myWriter.write(booking);
        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my code, ugly as it may be, I've been going at this for weeks and I have no clue why its not doing what I'm telling it to do

Comment: You are using Java not JavaScript....

Comment: JavaScript in a browser can not write to a file directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are loading libraries from Java, not JavaScript (`import java.io.FileWriter...`). Javascript in a browser cannot write data to files. You can use something like ajax and php, where you send data from your Javascript to php, and then use php to write the data to a file.

Here is some more info that should help you get started with using Ajax/PHP:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494
Remember you will need [jQuery](https://releases.jquery.com) to use ajax.

There are also other ways you can do this, ajax/php is just one of them.